# Keyboard not compatible with all phones

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

I just got xcode 6.1 and was running my app on it and the keyboards didnt come up when i clicked on the text fields in the simulator. Then I tried running the app on the iphone 5 simulator and it worked... Please let me know if you know how to make the keyboard compatible with all phones. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I do understand your problem correctly then you should go to 
iOS simulator go to hardware->keyboard -> uncheck the "Connect Hardware Keyboard"

Comment: Thank you, this works now! But in addition to this, when I run my apps on different phones, the project is not centered and I do have auto layout on. Any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: No , sorry , I don't use autoLayouts

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to uncheck the "Connect Hardware Keyboard" option. There is an option in the simulator, under the Hardware menu, Keyboard submenu named "Toggle Software Keyboard". This can get out of sync, so just hit command K when in a UITextField and it will return it to the normal operation you would expect. This is regardless of whether you have the hardware keyboard enabled or not.